# Node App - has TONS of hash looking files

Tags: npm

I have this NodeJS based app that when I copy the project recursively to another machine, I get a TON of hashy named files that are copied over.  This seems very excessive and suspicious if you ask me.  Does anyone know what these files are?  How to clean them out?   Do they generate when I `npm install` the node_modules for the projec?

I will have to look into the location and where these are, but for now
Here is a list of example filenames:

```
e5c6103b2fa3b069b1a5d93e94880ed462ff42                                                     100%  792     7.2KB/s   00:00
b17f52e8c6316d0c1954a49405cebe3dcc73c4                                                     100%   96     1.4KB/s   00:00
b6d713e3a587fb93d94ed3c0fa1e44837055c3                                                     100% 5816    61.1KB/s   00:00
a8d011c18bca43d21243abda256e8d6decd787                                                     100%  107     1.5KB/s   00:00
fcab10665b4f60ffa1faacdb4e90813ceacf2e                                                     100% 1666    15.8KB/s   00:00
a6115ca171ba017c32bc36fe4acb0154c3ded1                                                     100%  125     1.8KB/s   00:00
55b4704ec6f23e21568cb04814568d88c201cb                                                     100%   22KB 155.1KB/s   00:00
767ba8a406910cf5c6380b5987fc3625ce0217                                                     100%  805    11.1KB/s   00:00
637970b0d714880cd1453ce66d5ac8049e9871                                                     100%  429     5.8KB/s   00:00
37e66fa9115896e2e109f3df5873cb3add997f                                                     100%   80     1.1KB/s   00:00
82b8dc7d886526e3faf1c5494516d4eafc9565                                                     100% 2338    32.9KB/s   00:00
46d4437c80a16448aa2a0af98120ea4e48812f                                                     100% 2623    35.6KB/s   00:00
1191d6d1b8c7b0c22e572a0e95302bab121a35                                                     100% 4284    53.5KB/s   00:00
1c6aeacb13b886ccce6a00996ec62d7d2a0572                                                     100%  185     2.4KB/s   00:00
d1b5e9a7b0203efbf9edb7a54b905a4e8dcc00
```

The copy takes quite some time even on a fast connection.

Comment: Are you looking in your `.git` folder by chance?  Are they in your `.git/objects` dir?

Comment: I think they might be... I remember looking into this a long time ago and I think you might be right.  Currently I'm looking for one of these files by searching, and it's still looking... Been looking since I posted this question.

Comment: FYI, read about [Git Internals - Git Objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) or this brief look [inside the .git directory](https://githowto.com/git_internals_git_directory).